# npm needs higher node version to install higher node version...?

Tags: node.js, npm

I need to update nodejs on a Windows machine because error message from create-react-app. So now I first updated npm to latest version (6.11.3), then I want to update node (npm install node@latest -g) and I get error npm does not support Node.js v7.10.1

So how to update Node.js then? I don't want to loose the modules (including create-react-app) that are already installed. I found the advice to use nvm for this but npm install nvm -g also fails with error npm does not support Node.js v7.10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest, first removing your local install of node. Then please follow the instructions for installing [nvm windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows). Once installed you can use the command line to `nvm install 10` and `nvm use 10`

Comment: Tx. Can I do this without having to install all other modules, like create-react-app again? How?

Comment: Nvm will save node versions in folders named after the version number, there you will find a unique copy of global node modules for that version.

Comment: okay but then the current node installation that contains node 7 and create-react-app etc will still not have an updated node version?

Comment: Could you copy that folder, Install node 7 with nvm then replace the node modules folder with your copy?

Comment: I will give that a try. May take a day or two however before I have some time to try this. Thanks for now.

Comment: Make sure that your install the exact version to replace the modules with 7.16........ Bla Bla

Answer (score 0):

You could install node version manager(nvm) and can set appropriate node version for different projects [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)